# PostgreSQL limiting number of rows for a certain condition

Tags: postgresql, python

```
 arena_stat_id |      user_id       |          date_set          | level | trophies
---------------+--------------------+----------------------------+-------+----------
             1 | 281171949298647041 | 2020-05-20 15:03:04.45399  |     1 |        1
             2 | 281171949298647041 | 2020-05-20 15:03:29.965859 |     2 |        2
             3 | 281171949298647041 | 2020-05-20 15:18:09.736285 |     3 |        3
             4 | 281171949298647041 | 2020-05-20 15:46:52.785427 |     5 |        5
             5 | 281171949298647041 | 2020-05-20 15:47:13.433176 |     5 |        5
             6 | 281171949298647041 | 2020-05-20 15:47:17.521899 |     5 |        5
             7 | 281171949298647041 | 2020-05-20 15:47:27.557769 |     8 |        8
             8 | 281171949298647041 | 2020-05-20 15:47:32.147879 |     9 |        9
```

I have a table which stores some data on users, I want to limit the number of rows that each `user_id` can have to 7.

My current way of doing it is as follows in pseudo-code.

`INSERT INTO arena_stats (...)`

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM arena_stats WHERE user_id = $1;`

`IF count > 7: DELETE  OLDEST ROW`

I am hoping that there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Do you want to guarantee that there’s never more than 7 (a hard constraint)? Or is it a “soft” requirement and OK to simply delete the extras within milliseconds of them occurring? Do rows ever get deleted? Would you want to restore rows up to a max of 7 in that case? (Now I’m probably overthinking the problem!)

Comment: Its more of a soft constraint. I don't want to restore the rows, i only care about the most recent 7 since the previous ones will be outdated. I would want the 7 most recent rows (dependant on `date_set` to be kept

Comment: Don’t forget about concurrency issues.

Comment: Any suggestions then?

Comment: By more efficient, are you referring to the CPU and I/O resources required, or to a sexier SQL statement?  If you don't have the correct indexes, nothing will be efficient...